# What is the postgres equivalent of kql reduce

Tags: sql, postgresql, kql

What is the Postgres sql equivalent of [reduce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/reduceoperator) in kusto query language? I have a column with lots of variable parts that I would like to summarize.

Comment: You can't expect that everybody that knows Postgres also knows kql. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: I don't think the off-the-shelf PostgreSQL engine includes language processing functionality. Maybe there is some extra addon that can do something like this but it's not part of the core solution.